# Export a specific section from a given file in Linux

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

I have the below file and I want to export only specific group.
You can see that sometimes I have empty group that end with "End_section"
the end of the file can end without a specific word.
most of the groups can end between the word "Group"

How can I export separately each group?

```
Group 1:
ha
po
lo
Group 2:
ee
rr
tt
Group 3:
End_section
Group 4:
we
are
people
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Tried do it with sed but it doesn't give the all solution
`sed -e '/Group 2/,/Group: 3/p'`

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it